# Create page with different content types

Tags: entities, nodes

This should be something simple but I didn't figure out how to do it. Let's say I have three different content types: Client information, client projects and client updates.

I would like to have a "New client" node that will automatically create the three above content types.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Node Reference field on the "Client" content type. So you can reference from this node to another node like the Client Information which belongs to this Client.

To show all information at once, you can set the Node Reference field on "Manage Display" to render the full node.

Comment: Thanks. Actually node reference field is not supported in Drupal 7. The appropriate module for Drupal 7 is http://drupal.org/project/references.

Comment: AFAIK, references doesn't automatically create new content from reference, it has to already exist.

Comment: Right, but you can use the module "Node Connect" to allow the users to create new nodes directly from this fields.